# change multiple parameters for one name with variables in Azure DEVOPS

Tags: azure-devops

We have web application that works with MS SQL Server and Oracle DB.
When I create Release from Build for MS SQL Server I use *XML variable substitution* and it works for connectionString parameter setting. For Oracle DB Azure DevOps (on-premise) should also replace providerName param. 
We use same application build for both MS SQL Server and Oracle.
How to do that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with Variable groups Scoped to Release Stages

```
Release
- Stage 1: SQL
- Stage 2: Oracle
```

```
Variable Groups
- Variable Group Name: SQL
- Variable Name: providerName 
- Variable Value: SQLProvider


- Variable Group Name: Oracle
- Variable Name: providerName 
- Variable Value: OracleProvider
```

Back to Release

- Scope Variable Group "SQL" to "Stage 1: SQL"
- Scope Variable Group "Oracle" to "Stage 2: Oracle"

You can either clone the Stage in the release or my preferred approach is to Convert the tasks into a Task Group to reference it in each Stage.